# What format string can I use to parse an Oracle TIMESTAMP?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, datetime, datetime-format

I have the following value stored in an Oracle `TIMESTAMP` column `05-JAN-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM`.  I am trying to parse the values and convert them to something that is SQL Server `DATETIME` friendly. This is what I am trying to do:

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "05-JAN-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM",
    "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff tt", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,
    out result))
```

except this is not working because the format string does not have the precision to parse all of the milliseconds. How can I get around this? Is there a different format string I can use, or a better way to convert Oracle `TIMESTAMP` to `DateTime`?

Comment: I don't know the oracle syntax at all but if you use ANSI compliant format it will work in every RDBMS out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your modified question and data you need `fffffff00` for millisecond part.

```
   DateTime result;
   DateTime.TryParseExact(
       "10-JAN-12 03.51.35.028000000 PM",
       "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff00 tt",
       new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,
       out result);
```

For more see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I made an edit - there is an AM/PM in the stamp. Here is another example: `10-JAN-12 03.51.35.028000000 PM`

Comment: @IanO'Brien, for that you have to specify `fffffff00` as the maximum value for millisecond that can be parsed is upto 7 digits.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, maximum number of *significant digits of the seconds* is **seven** which is represent as `fffffff`.

That's why you *have to* remove `00` part on your original string's fraction part if you want to parse successfully.

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "05-JAN-18 12.00.00.0000000 AM",
    "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff tt", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,
    out result))
```

Or you can use string delimiter (if these two digits are always `00`) like;

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "05-JAN-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM",
    "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff'00' tt", 
    new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,
    out result))
```